# utserver: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install utorrent in my pc which has 20.04 ubuntu installed ,following this https://tipsonubuntu.com/2020/05/26/install-%C2%B5torrent-ubuntu-20-04/ guideline. But it can not start the server .

```
"utserver: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

Above error shows when i ran `utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-*/ &` command. What should I do?
Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Did you download and install the libssl.so.1.0.0 from the 18.04 repository like the instructions show and link to?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you forget to manually download required LibSSL library package. Download and install it with:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb
```

and then retry.

Comment: That worked.Thanks a lot !

Comment: Great, so you can accept this answer to mark problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @N0rbet answer,
You can find other versions in this link in case the link is outdated:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/

current link to download(5.7):
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.7_amd64.deb

[List of libssl packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vBdK.png)

Comment: Instead of adding this as a new answer, please edit the existing to include the correct links. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

#refact the top solution

cd ~/Downloads

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb

Comment: how to remove this