# ubuntu 22.04 error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install utorrent on my laptop ubuntu 22.04 LTS and when I type this command `utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-*/ &` I receive this message
`error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` 
I tried to do the solutions provide [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313466/utserver-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libssl-so-1-0-0-cannot-open-sha)
but I still get the same message

Comment: Install it from the Software Store.

Comment: AFAIK Ubuntu 22.04 uses libssl.so.3 so it looks like the version of utorrent that you are trying to use is not applicable